# hooks to update views in ruby/rails compared to php

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

PHP frameworks like "prestashop" make extensive use of hooks in the view. If you install an authorize.net payment module, then that module will change the view in certain sections of the app using a view hook.

The only thing that is similar to that in the Ruby world I could find was https://github.com/railsdog/deface. What else is out there?

It seems in Rails I can have an engine/railtie with a view but in this case I get a whole new page and I can do whatever. How does Rails ecosytem deal with the need of a gem to update part of the page? For example if I install the 'authroizedotnet' gem then, in the payment options along with other options like (check , cash, paypal), I could add a div record that would let people choose to pay using a credit card.